# Styling script inside of HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

I'm trying to style a stock widget taken from: [financialcontent.com](http://www.financialcontent.com/free-stock-market-widgets/market-snapshot.php). I am using Bootstrap to help style the page.

In order to place it inside of a div, I had to put the script itself inside of the HTML code I've written as shown below:

```
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 well">
        <script src="http://markets.financialcontent.com/stocks?Module=snapshot&Ticker=$COMP+$SPX+$DJI&Output=JS"></script>
    </div>
```

However, I cannot style the size of the stock which causes it to be bigger than the space I have allocated for it as shown below:

[image: Stocks]

Is there any way for me to edit the size of the script? I have already considered increasing the column size, but that is not an attractive option considering other elements of the page.

Comment: Assuming that script is just injecting some markup into your page, you should be able to use your developer tools (F12 for most browsers on a Windows machine, or `Cmd + Opt + I` for Chrome and Firefox on OSX) to inspect the generated HTML. From that, you may find some classes that you can style in your CSS.

Answer (score 1):

The width is hard-coded to 300px:

```
document.write('<div class="fcsnapshot" style="width: 300px;">\n');
```

You can overwrite that with a CSS rule

```
.fcsnapshot { width: auto !important; }
```

This will likely break other styles in the widget you have to fix, but it's a starting point.